# How to enforce sandbox rules for the particular app?

Tags: macos, security, sandbox

I wrote an sandbox specification file (inspired by files from `/usr/share/sandbox` and manuals like [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100318044558156)) and now I can launch some app in sandbox with `sandbox-exec $path_to_rules /Applications/$appname.app/Content/...`. Fine.

Is there a way to enforce the rules when the app is started in regular way (Finder's "Open with...", etc)?

I thought about replacing the binary inside .app with wrapper script but it will be overwritten after app update and I will need to restore it every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the binary, or even change the Info.plist, but like changing the binary you make will need to do this again each time the app is updated. There's no way to do this without changing the app in a way that won't be overwritten when it's updated.

You can automatically make your changes with a Launch Agent.
Save the following in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` as `com.yourname.youragent.plist`, then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.yourname.youragent.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.yourname.youragent</string>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>cp</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/grgarside/test/MyApp</string>
            <string>/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/</string>
        </array>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

The above script will watch the `WatchPaths` for any modifications (in this case, it's watching the binary for an app) and will run `cp` to copy your binary to the app in /Applications.

Comment: I'm thinking about auto-patching installed apps. Is there a way to run my script automatically every time something in `/Applications` is changed? And also to forbid any app to modify itself.

Comment: @Equidamoid You can use LaunchAgents; edited answer

Comment: so, in your example it will run `cp /Users/.../MyApp /Applications...` every time MyApp binary is changed? Thanks!

Comment: @Equidamoid Yes, exactly!